# Correct punctuation to separate the elements of this sentence

Tags: punctuation

The sentence in question is

> Returns the value of the function as if it were attached to this attribute ( ) under a fast evaluation ( ) according to the current state.

It feels like there should be some punctuation in the place of the `( )`. Should they be commas? Should the first be colon and the second a comma.
Should there be punctuation at all?

Although I understand the words let me add that English is not my first language.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me. But whatever it means, it's not a *sentence*, since there's no grammatical "subject" for the verb ***returns***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It appears to be related to programming/mathematics (I may be wrong) but summaries and documentations often omit subjects because summaries sit on top of the thing that they're describing, so it's inferred. [See here for an example.](http://horstmann.com/sjsu/fall2012/cs46a/lecture5/method_summary.png)

Comment: @The Anathema: I never suggested such constructions don't occur in special contexts. But by most people's definition it's not a *sentence*.

Comment: It depends on how those clauses are related. Is it attached under a fast evaluation? Or does it return under a fast evaluation? Without more context (or programming knowledge), we don't know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, there is an implicit subject.

Comment: @dangph: That's stretching a point. I guess most grammarians would accept imperatives such as *Be quiet!* as "sentences" with implied subject ***you***, but I never heard anyone defend OP's "technical documentation" example as being a valid sentence where the implied subject is whatever is actually being documented.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, it's a simple fact that the sentence in question contains an implicit, elided subject. If we had a function in a computer program called Sum(x, y) and there was a comment on it saying "Returns the sum of x and y," then the implicit subject is "the function below", or "Sum(x, y)".

Answer (score 2):

You might consider reordering the sentence like so:

"Returns the value of the function, according to the current state, as if it were attached to this attribute **and** under a fast evaluation."

Without context, I'm not sure if the bolded **and** should stay or be removed.

Comment: I think this is the right approach. Rewrite the sentence to make its structure less ambiguous.